# fs.symlink gives me ELOOP errors

Tags: node.js, filesystems, symlink

```
> fs.symlinkSync('client', 'build/client', 'dir')

> fs.statSync('build/client/index.js')
Error: ELOOP, too many symbolic links encountered 'build/client/index.js'
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:679:18)
    at repl:1:5
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the target directory to be relative or absolute:

```
fs.symlinkSync('../client', 'build/client', 'dir');
```

I confirmed the behavior to be the same when using the same directory structure and path names in `symlink(2)`:

```
// Directory structure
build/
client/
  –> index.js

// Fails
$ ln -s client build/client 
$ stat build/client/index.js
stat: build/client/index.js: stat: Too many levels of symbolic links

// Works
$ ln -s ../client build/client 
$ stat build/client/index.js
stat: <outputs file stats>
```

The target HAS to be relative or absolute. Even though in node we know `client` will resolve to the `cwd` in a require call or even an `fs.read/write`, this is not the case in `fs.symlink` which is an alias for `symlink(2)`.

### Update:

My reasoning is confirmed by the Unix/Linux guys. [See this post for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105637/is-symlinks-target-relative-to-the-destinations-parent-folder-and-if-so-why).